# libgdx table equal spacing between buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, button, libgdx

I am trying to get equal space between my buttons across the screen for any screen size (width). I am using Libgdx tables inside a stage. I think my logic is on the right track but it is not returning anything close to what I want.. most of the buttons are off the screen. (I have 5 buttons total)

```
    int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    int spacing = width / 5;
    System.out.println(width);
    System.out.println(spacing);

    //BOTTOM TABLE
    tableBottom = new Table(skin);
    stage.addActor(tableBottom);
    tableBottom.setBounds(0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    tableBottom.setFillParent(true);
    tableBottom.columnDefaults(1).width(spacing);
    tableBottom.add(inventoryButton).size(144,160).center();
    tableBottom.add(assignButton).size(148,180).center();
    tableBottom.add(shopButton).size(130,152).center();
    tableBottom.add(collectButton).size(182,198).center();
    tableBottom.add(fightButton).size(162,178).center();
```

As Requested Images:

This is what the code above is doing! and it is not accurate it does different based on every screen size.

[image: what is happening]

This is what I WANT it to look like. On every Sized screen equal spacing and take up the whole bottom.. obviously a bigger screen they will be not as close together but that is fine! thanks been struggling with this.

[image: what I want it to be doing]

Comment: Can you maybe post a photo of what you have vs what you want?

Comment: @grimrader22 I have EDITED the post to include pictures, thanks!

Comment: Well that's the thing I can decrease it and make it look fine... But when I go to a tablet for example its not the same spacing as the android phone... I need to dynamically change the spacing based on the width of the screen. Which is what I thought I was doing by taking the screen width and diving it by the buttons and using that has the spacing but that is pushing them off screen.

Comment: What if you remove the `.width(spacing)` altogether? and the `.center()`s?

Comment: The .width(spacing) is setting the default width of the table cell and center is placing it in the center of that cell column. My logic is taking the screen width and making 5 equal cells from the width and then placing the buttons in the center of each of those cells. But it runs of screen and doesn't do what I expect.. There has to be a way people do this.

Comment: Well you shouldn't have to manually set the width of each table cell. It should manage itself, and fit everything in to its width without it. Does nothing change if you remove it?

Comment: If I take out the width and centers the buttons are all pushed  up against each other in the left side of the screen

Comment: That's good. Then do `table.center()`, and then where you had your `.center()`s, you can add `.padLeft(width / 10).padRight(width / 10)`. Or some other value for `width/10`

Comment: Actually instead of doing `.padLeft()...` you should do `.expandX()` for all of your cells where you had `center()`

Comment: Ahhh yes okay I see what your getting at now I think that might actually work nicely! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get equal spacing in horizontal direction change

```
tableBottom.add(inventoryButton).size(144,160).center();
tableBottom.add(assignButton).size(148,180).center();
tableBottom.add(shopButton).size(130,152).center();
tableBottom.add(collectButton).size(182,198).center();
tableBottom.add(fightButton).size(162,178).center();
```

to

```
tableBottom.add(inventoryButton).size(144,160).expandX();
tableBottom.add(assignButton).size(148,180).expandX();
tableBottom.add(shopButton).size(130,152).expandX();
tableBottom.add(collectButton).size(182,198).expandX();
tableBottom.add(fightButton).size(162,178).expandX();
```